# Sometimes (quite frequently) Chromium doesn't start up

Tags: chromium

I've been having a problem with the Chromium browser.Sometimes when I want to open it,I click on it,the icon appears at the bottom of the screen,the pointer shows that the browser is loading and after 15 second nothing happens and the icon at the bottom of the screen dissapears.

When this happens,the only way to fix it temporarily is to open Chromium many times (doesn't matter if it's all at once or not).After that,it works normally for a while...then it starts acting again and I need to repeat the process.

Don't know if it's relevant,but I'm using KDE on Ubuntu 13.04.

Any way of solving this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I recently got ubuntu 13.04 and it happened to me a few times so I just installed normal Chrome and it sorted all my issues and I haven't had any problems since.

Hope this helped.